# CSS external sheet needs full path link instead of folder path. Why?

Tags: css, styles, external

[Picture of code](https://i.stack.imgur.com/6vh1d.png)

As with line 8 of my code, I should be able to link to the style sheet I need in a neighboring folder. But, that doesn't work and instead I need the full path.

In the online course I'm following, the instructor has it work that way except that they use css/styles.css I think because they're on a mac. I do css\styles.css because I'm on windows.

Also, even if I try going higher in the folders like doing Web Development\css\styles.css, that doesn't work either. It only works when I go all the way back to C: and so forth.

UPDATE: deleting `<html lang="en" dir="ltr">` fixed it, but why?

Any tips?

Answer (score 1):

there is no css folder adjacent to the `index.html` file, you can use `..` to go folder up and then go into the `css` folder and select the `styles.css` file.

```
<link rel="stylesheet" href="../css/styles.css">
```

Comment: I see, thanks! I'll save this for the future. However, I just found out that deleting `<html lang="en" dir="ltr">` fixed my issue. Do you have any idea why, maybe the `dir=`?

Comment: `<html>` element acts as the root element of the webpage and should not be removed. the `dir` attribute tells about the direction of the webpage, the value `ltr` means that the page's layouts from `left to right`.

Answer (score 0):

in your code, there is no such file path like your code try this one
`<link rel="stylesheet" href="/css/css.css">`